# In AS3, how would I pass the contents of an object as arguments for a function?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

For example, I have a function:

```
function doSomething( a:String, b:Number, c:Array ):void {
  trace( a + b + c.toString() );
}
```

…and I have an object that has all the elements I would want to pass arguments:

```
var args:Object = { 'dog', 11, myArray };
```

…and I want to be able to pass the contents of args to doSomething without making any changes to doSomething (assume it's someone else's function) and I'd like to do it in a way that doesn't assume I will know anything about the contents of args.

Is this possible?

Comment: There is something strage with your Object. Shouldn't it be more like: var args:Object = { var1:"dog", var2:11, var3:myArray }; ?

Comment: I just noticed that.  Your args:Object should be more like { "pet": "dog", "count": 11, "bar": myArray } .  Did you mean this as an Array instead of an Object?

Comment: Sorry, assume it's whatever it would take to make it work, be it an array or a (correctly assigned) object. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to use is [Function.apply()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Function.html#apply%28%29). To do this you will need to change the 'args' Object from your example to an Array.

Then you would construct objects like:

```
var myObject:Object = { command: doSomething, args: [ "dog", 11, myArray ] };
```

Where `command` is a reference to the Function to be called and `args` is the list of arguments that `command` requires. Then, to call the `doSomething`:

```
myObject.command.apply(this, myObject.args)
```

As an added bonus this will work with any function with any number of arguments, all you need to do is change the values for `command` and `args` in `myObject`. So you could pass in a list of objects that conform to these rules and loop over them without having to change any of this code.

Answer (score 5):

Are you a Python developer?  ;)

You have to turn your args:Object into an args:Array and then call doSomething.apply(this, argsArray).  The trouble here is that your arguments in the args:Object are not ordered, and thus looping over them to turn them into an Array to pass to apply() will not result in a predictable sequence of arguments.

Unless you have a strategy to enforce the correct order of properties in the Object-to-Array conversion, it sounds like a no go.

Comment: Ok, assuming I have the data in an Array, but I can't change the doSomething function, and there is a doSomethingElse function with a different set of parameters that will also be called by this same mystery function and passed a completely different set of parameters… am I still SOL?   E.g., an object has { command:doSomething, args: new Array( "dog", 11, myArray ) } and { command:doSomethingElse args: new Array( "apple", "pear", "bannana" ) } and I want to iterate through the object making calls to the commands and passing the elements of args. Is there any hope?

Comment: @Seanonymous That's what [Function.apply()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Function.html#apply()) does. Using the example in your comment you'd just be able to call `myObject.command.apply(this, myObject.args)`.

Comment: @NoobsArePeople2 is exactly right. Every function in AS3 itself has a function called apply() that lets you call the function on a specified scope (first parameter) and passing the function an Array of arbitrary arguments (the second argument). In that case you are perfectly fine. The only problem is using a hashmap-style Object instead of an indexed Array. Use an Array and you're golden.

Comment: Thanks, @NoobsArePeople2 - Would you mind moving that comment out into a separate answer so I can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your object values as

```
var args:Object = { a:'dog', b:11, c:myArray };
function doSomething( args.a, args.b, args.c );
```

Comment: Right, but I'm looking for a way around that, if there is one.  I'm trying to cache calls that are being made to an object that won't be loaded in time to receive them, so I'm placing all the function calls to the object into an array that will then make the calls once the object has loaded.  So, I won't know what the arguments are because they'll be different for each call.

Comment: You can also use toString() method of the object, to get it as formated string and then parse it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Right I've now added another method that can take any number of arguments, in any form. It will essentially give you an Array of parameters to handle.

```
private var _testObject:Object;

private function init():void{
    _testObject = {str:"test", num:11, arr:["test","array"]};
    doSomething(_testObject.str, _testObject.num, _testObject.arr);
}

private function doSomething(...args):void{
    trace(args.toString());
}
```

Of course that will need to be inside a class or a script tag, but if you call the init method you should see the following trace: test,11,test,array

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok I've just read your comment below the previous answer, can you expand on how you are receiving the calls that you want to cache?